# Real time audio playback and monitor on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I am trying to get the iPhone to play recordings on the microphone back in real time without saving any files.

It was very easy to record to a file using AVAudioRecorder, however I cannot play it back until recording ends and the audio file is saved.

What goes into the microphone comes out of the headphones in real time if you will.

Comment: This objective-c library [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio) might be useful, even though this project was deprecated at June 13, 2016. Check the example called PassThrough in this project

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.